# Java run time error in my spring Java app

Tags: java, spring, java-8, unsupported-class-version

I am novice to Java and i directly started learning Java Spring (do not know if this is good idea).
I have made simple main class file, i did 'run as java project' and I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/springdemo/MyApp has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Following is my code:

[image: Code and error snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Check your java version. Class version 53 indicates that Java 9 was used to compile the code. But in your screenshot jave 8 library added to the project can be seen (Java 8 expects class version 52 or below).

Right Click on your project, go to properties and in the properties window check the "Java Compiler" tab. May be there java 1.9 is selected.

Comment: Ohh yeah ...... compiler version was the issue ........... thanks Kaustabh !

Comment: Most welcome sir